# CMS for an artist to display art work?

Tags: cms

I am helping a friend put together a website for an artist.  The person wants a very simple looking site to display their artwork, but will want to have an image slider and a few pages where they can change the text themselves.

Does anyone know of a good CMS and/or template for this kind of project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Wordpress alongwith one of the many [gallery-related themes](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/16/20-gorgeous-wordpress-gallery-themes/)

Comment: Agreed. Wordpress is simple enough for any basic user to get the swing of it in a few minutes/hours. I would also recommend Drupal because of it's extreme extensibility. The only problem with Drupal is that their upgrade process is painful (even via SSH). I know it's an issue being worked on, but I haven't checked in the last few months to see where it's at.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently custom-coding UltraPanel PRO CMS to run [this site](http://www.boiseart.net/sections/list/).

Comment: You might take a look at the encoding on those JPG's - 57kb is heavy for a single 200x200 image...

Comment: @danlefree Thanks for the tip - I totally haven't had time to optimize it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I ended up using (and customizing) the [F8 Lite theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/f8-lite) on Wordpress.

[This blog post](http://kirastackhouse.com/2009/03/15/f8-lite-wp-theme-how-to-get-images-to-appear/) explains how to use it.